# Macaulayfications and standard blow-ups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $X$ be an affine variety such that $X-p$ is Cohen-Macaulay, 
and let $\pi \colon \widetilde{X} \rightarrow X$ be a standard blow-up of $X$
with respect to $\mathcal{O}_X$, centered at $p$.
It is known that $\widetilde{X}$ is Cohen-Macaulay.

If the blow-up of $X$ at the maximal ideal corresponding to $p$ is Cohen-Macayulay, is it true that such blow-up is standard?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by standard blow up?